# R, PHP & Apache

Tags: php, security, apache-2.2

I designed a web page that lets user define some criteria using drop-boxes etc. and php collects the relevant data from the database according to that criteria.

What I intend to do is modeling a least squares trend line over that data using R and displaying coefficients and plot etc.

But I'm unable to run R, though it's installed in the server and works as expected when invoked within the server. I guess there are some security issues.

Can anyone lead me to a solution. My hosting company says it's impossible to run a exec() command to invoke R within PHP because of security reasons.

Thanks so much,
jan

Comment: Sounds like your hosting company sucks.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a trending class in pure PHP as part of PHPExcel, to provides the functions for calculating coefficients and plot. It should provide everything that R can provide. As an alternative to running R itself, you can find it on the [PHPExcel](http://www.phpexcel.net) site at codeplex. If you can't find an exec() solution, you're welcome to pillage that code to provide a pure PHP solution, though I'd appreciate any feedback/bugfixes/etc

Comment: Actually I'm thinking of developing the project so that it is capable of doing more complex calculations, like neural-network estimations. Besides, I've written a ready-to-use model in R. But your project seems like my next stop if getting R to work fails, at least as a start. Indeed, it looks like excellent for other but similar purposes! Good work & thanks!

Comment: Only suggested as a fallback alternative. R is a far better and more efficient tool for the job if you can get it working with PHP

Answer (score 1):

There is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046881/using-r-with-apache-php) about configuring R right here on SO. Not all the answers are using exec().

Comment: I've seen that post but in that post Brendon says he found better answers in other forums. Actually, I was trying to ask this question directly to Brandon but I found myself here and edited the question as a general question :$

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for an answer to your question also, and by now all that I have read said that you will need more privileges on your server (which you won't get on shared hosting).

Potentially going do a virtual dedicated server would work for you, but I don't know yet of someone saying that he did it and that it works.

I wrote about projects to get R online [on my blog here](http://www.r-statistics.com/category/r-and-the-web/) (like [ggplot2 web interface](http://www.r-statistics.com/2010/04/jeroen-oomss-ggplot2-web-interface-a-new-version-released-v0-2/) and [R-node](http://www.r-statistics.com/2010/04/r-node-a-web-front-end-to-r-with-protovis/)),  If you find good solutions, please let me (us) know.

Best,

Tal

Comment: Hi Tal,

In fact, this man (Matthew Jockers) here seems to achieve exactly what I wanted. I followed his instructions step by step with no luck, but it may be useful for you and your blog: http://www.stanford.edu/~mjockers/cgi-bin/drupal/node/25

I guess, it's mostly about privileges on the server, as you said. I have a virtual dedicated server in my hands but and I'm dealing with my provider ATM.

Thanks,
jan

Comment: Thank you for the link Jan - very interesting !  Best, Tal

Answer (score 1):

You may check this site: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#R-Web-Interfaces
On the other hand, some time ago I was making something similar and I used a named pipe through which PHP was sending commands to a constantly running R instance, which was then putting its output directly to the database. In this solution the pipe served as a queue, so it could survive multiple clients at one time.